# How to replace value of place holder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell programming. I have two files:

1. eg.txt
2. file.sh

The eg.txt file has some HTML content and file.sh cotains a shell script. 
In the script a value is assigned to the `temp` variable, and that value should be injected into the HTML file.

**eg.txt**

```
<html>
  Hi MGM ,<br/>
  One alert has been received !!<br/>

 Here is the event Data.<br/><br/>

 <font size=‘1’>{temp}</font>
 <br/><br/>
 Regards,
 WDTS Supports.
 </html>
```

**file.sh**

```
echo $1
temp=56

(
echo "To:"$1
echo "Subject: Alert Updates !! "
echo "Content-Type: text/html"

echo cat eg.txt
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

echo "Mail sent !!"
```

Comment: Remember `!` has special meanings in bash. Check [\[ this \]](http://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found).

Answer (score 3):

With sed :

```
sed "s/{temp}/$temp/" eg.txt | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

You can also use `printf` to inject variables in your template :

**file.sh**

```
temp=56
tpl=$(cat "eg.txt")

printf "$tpl" "$1" "$temp" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

**eg.txt**

```
To:%s
Subject: Alert Updates !!
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
  Hi MGM ,<br/>
  One alert has been received !!<br/>

 Here is the event Data.<br/><br/>

 <font size=‘1’>%s</font>
 <br/><br/>
 Regards,
 WDTS Supports.
 </html>
```

**Update:**

If multiple variables, just write  multiple substitute commands  (and update placeholders in eg.txt):

```
sed "s/{temp1}/$temp1/;s/{temp2}/$temp2/" eg.txt | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: No harm in addinf the `g` with sed I guess but why bother? ;)

Comment: I am working this command, but emails are going to spam. Can anyone tell me how to deal with this. It should come in my inbox

Comment: Try to remove the `!!` from Subject in eg.txt

Comment: @Kenavoz i was working with multilple temp like temp 1 temp 2 etc but its not giving me answer.

Comment: What do to tou watt to achieve with thèse temps variables? You should édit your question

Comment: @Kenavoz i had taken temp=56 in last example. Now i am taking two more variable like temp1=34, temp2=45. So i want to know how to write sed for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have introduced some error checking to your code :

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=56
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "Usage : ./file.sh user_name_to_mail to"
exit -1
else
    if id "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 #Check if user exists, suppress stdout, stderr
    then
      mail_header=$(echo -e "To: $1\nSubject: Alert Updates"'!!'"\nContent-Type: text/html\n")
      mail_body=$(awk -v var="$temp" '{print gensub(/{temp}/,var,"g"$0)}' eg.txt)
      echo -e "$mail_header\n$mail_body" | sendmail -t                   
    else
      echo -e "Sorry! Invalid User\n"
      exit -1 # The error code is set to  detect failure
    fi
fi
```

To prevent the mails going to spam you need to have a valid SPF record for  domain from which you're sending email. Check [[ this ]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81440/25919) for a starting point.

---

**Note:**

`!` is a special character to bash, it is used to refer to previous command. To work around this problem I have used `..Updates"'!!'"\nContent-Type..`. 
Inside the single quotes the `!` loses its special meaning.

---

**Interesting reads :**

1. What is an [[ SPF ]](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) record?
2. Open SPF [[ documentation ]](http://www.openspf.org/Implementations) .

Comment: You can simplify: `if id "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then`

Comment: I don't agree, to be honest I don't see how it can be more explicit than: `if this_thing; then`. Wrapping in command substitutions implies OP is familiar with `$?`. And even if they are, it's still practice to teach.

Comment: @andlrc : Hmm... Changed :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $1
temp=56

    (
    echo "To:"$1
    echo "Subject: Alert Updates !! "
    echo "Content-Type: text/html"

    awk -F "" -v var=$temp '{gsub(/{temp}/,var,$0); print}' < eg.txt 
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

echo "Mail sent !!"
```

added awk to '|' where the temp is stored in awk variable : *var* which is later replaced

```
awk -F "" -v var=$temp '{gsub(/{temp}/,var,$0); print}'
```

Comment: Beware: [UUoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat/) — Useless Use of `cat`.

Comment: Working with this command but emails are going in spam. How to resolve this. Emails should come in Inbox.